# How can I make apt-listbugs forget about pinned packages of already seen bugs?

Tags: package-management

I installed apt-listbugs to be aware of all the possible important bugs before installing any package from testing. I decided to pin the packages since there was grave bugs that would prevent me from booting my system.

Now, the bugs are result of a misconfiguration which I don't have, therefore I decided to upgrade the packages, but I don't see a way to make apt-listbugs to forget/unpin them in their options.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `apt-listbugs` file in the `/etc/apt/preferences.d` directory. When you upgrade, if the bugs aren't marked as "Done" it will ask you again about what to do.